# site data not populated as browser, despite rendering with html-requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests-html

I am experimenting with `html-requests` on various sites,
and I am having trouble extracting the price of a stock on this particular site:

https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/BABA/quote

I am using html-requests, and using `html.render` to render javascript.
Despite this, the data doesn't seem to be populated as it is within the browser.

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
import requests_html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'
requests_html.DEFAULT_USER_AGENT = user_agent



def get_request(ticker):
    
    session = HTMLSession()
    print(url)
    res = session.get(url)
    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except ValueError as e:
        raise('Dead link')

    return res


def mstar():
    
    url = 'https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/BABA/quote'
    
    res = get_requesturl)
    res.html.render()
    
    price = res.html.find('div#message-box-price.message-partial.fill.up')[0].text
    print(price)

    price = res.html.find('div.message-partial.fill.up')[0].text
    print(price)
    
    change = res.html.find('div#message-box-percentage')[0].text
    print(change)
```

The Expected outcome is this data:

```
262.20
4.26 | 1.65%
```

However,
either I am just getting back symbols:
`-` or  `%` but no actual prices.

Any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: I don't find the price of a stock on this page.

Comment: Hi, it's right above the chart, if you scroll about 1/4 down the page. I just checked again. The quotes are within a green box.

Comment: required information not present in HTML it comes from an JSON API response ```https://api-global.morningstar.com```. check Network tab in chrome for more details

Answer (score 1):

The data is generated by the JSON API and then dynamically inserted into the website via JavaScript, hence `python requests` cannot see it. You can verify it yourself by doing a `curl https://www.morningstar.com/stocks/xnys/baba/quote` and trying to find the `1.65%` on it -- it is not there, simply because it is not in the HTML source.

I would suggest to use [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead, and parse the data as follows:

```
elements = driver.find_element(By.ID, "div")
for element in elements:
    print element.text
    print element.get_attribute('message-box-price.message-partial.fill.up')
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I am using `requests-html` which renders `javascript` via `pypuppeter` which is very similar to selenium but more robust.

Comment: My apologies, I missed that. I have made an edit to the tag from python-requests to python-requests-html.